# Why does the DNNRegressor in tensorflow.estimator cannot fit to a sin function?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, regression

I am a new comer to tensorflow and its estimators. I try to use its DNNRegressor to fit data generated by a sin function. However, it does not work and it seems that the regressor fail to work. I would appreciate if any experienced researher or engineer could give me an answer. Thanks a lot!

```
import tensorflow as tf;
import numpy as np;

x = np.arange(100);
y = np.sin(x);

feature_column = tf.feature_column.numeric_column("variable");

train_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(x = {"variable":x}, y=y, num_epochs = None, shuffle=True);
test_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(x = {"variable":x}, num_epochs = 1, shuffle=False);

estimator = tf.estimator.DNNRegressor([50,50], feature_columns=[feature_column]);
estimator.train(input_fn=train_input_fn, steps = 1000);
```

Comment: I'm curious to know if it would work with a higher sampling resolution per sine wave, for example if you use "y = np.sin(x/10)". IWould you please make this test?

Comment: Thanks a lot, James. Yes, when I increase the sampling resolution of sine wave, it works. Another point is the size of batch. I think the gradients of BP may be misleading when the size of batch is too small.

Comment: Have a look at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem, it explains that for wave forms you need sampling of at least 2* the maximum frequency you expect to pick up.